# io_uring: What is the use case for flag IORING_REGISTER_FILES_SKIP

Tags: io-uring

In liburing library, after initial registration of file descriptors using `io_uring_register_files` api, we could use `io_uring_register_files_update` to update the file descriptors. The file descriptor can be set to special value `IORING_REGISTER_FILES_SKIP`. What is specific use case of this flag usage?

```
Note: Taken from liburing file_register.c test

io_uring_register_files(ring, files, 100);
files[90] = IORING_REGISTER_FILES_SKIP;
io_uring_register_files_update(ring, 90, &files[90], 1);

test_fixed_read_write(ring, 90); // This will use file index 90 with sqe flag IOSQE_FIXED_FILE
```

In above code is test_fixed_read_write() be successful? If yes, then what is the use of flag `IORING_REGISTER_FILES_SKIP`?

Comment: I think I understood now the use case. The special value `IORING_REGISTER_FILES_SKIP` is used when we do not want to update that specific index when using `io_uring_register_files_update`, but update fds in all other index which do not have `io_uring_register_files_update`

Answer (score 0):

IORING_REGISTER_FILES_SKIP = -2;

-1 has been used to indicate that the entry has been removed